# Given a choice between writing a new class which implements an existing interface, or extending an existing class, which should I do and why?

Tags: typescript

In Java and/or C#, I think I should inherit from an existing class (which also inherits from the interface: `interface IFoo` -> `class Foo` -> `class FooChild`), rather than creating a completely new class which adheres to the same interface (`interface IFoo` -> `class Foo` and `interface IFoo` -> `class Bar`).

In C++ I would try to avoid inheritance all along, and weigh whether I truly need polymorphism to solve the problem.

And so on and so forth for different languages. But what about TypeScript?

If it is possible, my question is about the default choice one should make for TypeScript, without any context.

However, just in case, here's what I am trying to do:

I want to have a class which implements a type with dynamic property names:

```
type Dispatcher <
    Prefix extends string,
    Names extends string,
    Suffix extends string,
    Value extends unknown,
> = {
    [Name in Names as `${ Prefix }${ Name }${ Suffix }`]: Value
};

type Foo = { /* ... */ };

type Bar <Names extends string> =
    Readonly <Dispatcher <"prop_01_", Names, "", Foo>> &
    Readonly <Dispatcher <"prop_02_", Names, "", Foo>> &
    Readonly <Dispatcher <"prop_03_", Names, "", Foo>>;

type BarSpecialized = Bar <"bar_01" | "bar_02">;

// type BarSpecialized produces type:
// BarSpecialized === {
//     readonly prop_01_bar_01: Foo;
//     readonly prop_01_bar_02: Foo;
//
//     readonly prop_02_bar_01: Foo;
//     readonly prop_02_bar_02: Foo;
//
//     readonly prop_03_bar_01: Foo;
//     readonly prop_03_bar_02: Foo;
// }
```

ideally this should be possible:

```
class Baz <Names extends string> 
    implements Bar <Names> // ERROR: A class can only implement an object type or intersection of object types with statically known members. ts(2422)
{ /* ... */ }
```

and while this is not ideal:

```
class Baz01 
    implements Bar <"Baz01_01" | "Baz01_02"> 
{ /* ... */ }

class Baz02
    implements Bar <"Baz02_01" | "Baz02_02" | "Baz02_03"> 
{ /* ... */ }

class Baz02
    implements Bar <"Baz03_01" | "Baz03_02" | "Baz03_03" | "Baz03_04"> 
{ /* ... */ }
```

(**Note**: classes: `Baz01`, `Baz02`, `Baz03` implement common interface `Bar`.)

I can make this work.

But at the same, this situation led me to question myself, whether should I rewrite `type Bar` into this:

```
type Bar <Names extends string> = {
    readonly prop_01: Readonly <Dispatcher <"", Names, "", Foo>>;
    readonly prop_02: Readonly <Dispatcher <"", Names, "", Foo>>;
    readonly prop_03: Readonly <Dispatcher <"", Names, "", Foo>>;
}

class Baz <Names extends string>
    implements Bar <Names>
{ /* ... */ }

class Baz01 
    extends Baz <"Baz01_01" | "Baz01_02"> 
{ /* ... */ }

class Baz02
    extends Bar <"Baz02_01" | "Baz02_02" | "Baz02_03"> 
{ /* ... */ }

class Baz02
    extends Bar <"Baz03_01" | "Baz03_02" | "Baz03_03" | "Baz03_04"> 
{ /* ... */ }
```

(**Note**: classes: `Baz01`, `Baz02`, `Baz03` extend common class `Baz` which implements interface `Bar`.)